# Why is my ASP website so slow?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-vista, asp

I currently run a ColdFusion 9 website on my local machine - Windows Vista with IIS 7.

I have never worked with ASP. I am currently working on some HTML and CSS changes to an ASP website.

I downloaded the webfiles via FTP, and added the site to IIS - and left the default settings alone. I created a local domain for the website (my-asp-site.dev), and added it to my hosts file. The site loads, however, EVERY HTTP request (CSS, JS, PNG, GIF, JPG) it makes takes extremely long. This happens even when I run a simple HTML page with no ASP code.

The ColdFusion website loads normally - no lag at all in loading JS, CSS, or images.

What am I doing wrong?

FYI, I also installed Visual Web Developer Express 2010, and this all seems to have gotten worse since then.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance that the path to the my-asp-site.dev domain is going through a proxy, or that you have a tool like fiddler or firebug that could be slowing down requests to that page?

Normally fiddler/firebug won't slow down the site, but sometimes it will.  If it's not from those tools, then try using them to see what's happening.  You will hopefully see a pattern.

What you're getting isn't expected or normal, so some proxy setting is likely coming into play.

Comment: +1 for the mention of Fiddler.

Comment: No proxy. And I am using Firebug - that's how I'm seeing the extremely slow load times.

Comment: What happens if you call the images directly?  Can you repro the slowness?  Try in another browser too and see if it still occurs, just in case firebug is adding overhead.  Also, try pinging the ip for my-asp-site.dev just to make sure that it has a direct immediate path to the site.

Comment: Yes, if I call the images or scripts directly, I get the same lag. I've tried it in IE, Firefox, and Chrome. I will try the ping.